# buyer Shipping rate depends on seller in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Hi I am using woocommerce as vendor so i want to set two shipping zones without any country means rates of shipping depends on seller/vendor 
Is it possible?
here is my flow chart

Admin Side
In Backend there are two zones of shipping 
1. Ship to my country *(5,7,10)
2. Rest Of World *(5,10,15)

Vendor/ seller
Must select his country(on whcih shipping will caluculate for buyer)

Buyer: 
When

```
 if { buyer country = seller country
shipping rate = Ship to my country zone (i.e 5,7 10)
else {
 buyer country != Seller country
   shipping rate = Rest Of World (i.e 5,10 15)
}
```

*Here rates in $ fir small, Medium and large packets.

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not a option in woocommerce for multi-vendor 
I.e if buyer and seller country match then shipping price changed

Only Admin can set shipping to seller and buyer